# Basic database design : list of instances of type

Tags: database-design

Suppose we have a blogging website with many users, each of whom have a few blog posts.  We want to quickly find all articles written by a given user.  We could search the post table for all blog posts with the given userID.  We could also design the user table to have a list of the user's posts.  This would mean, perhaps, storing a string of comma separated post IDs.  What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization), a technique which prevents:

- Redundancy (storing the same data more than once)
- Anomalies (changing one datum changes another)
- Cycles (Changing A changes B which changes C which changes A)
- Coupling (changing one field requires changing other fields)
- Bias (different ways of asking the same question gives different answers)

The typical form of normalization is called [Boyce-Codd Normal Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyce%E2%80%93Codd_normal_form) and is, in general, quite difficult to do, but you can improve your design by implementing the lower [Normal Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form).

You have not given us enough information to recommend a schema for you, but “storing a string of comma separated post IDs” is the wrong thing to do if you need to distinguish between post IDs. If that’s what you want you should consider a design like:

```
Users
userID    other user fields ..
   100    Charlie
   101    Edith

Articles
articleID  userID  pathOrWhatever...
     1000     100  http://example.com/stuff
     1001     100  http://example.com/moreStuff
     1002     101  http://example.com/somethingElse
```

This design can get articles from users, or users from articles, from database commands.

Comment: Thanks Arch.  I have another question.  I assume that databases implement red black trees over primary key, but what about every other column?  How is it efficient to search the document table by the secondary column of userID?

Comment: Totally dependent on what database technology you use. Most allow tuning lookup for performance without affecting the data.

Comment: @user442920 Relational databases don't generally use red-black trees - they are good for in-memory operation but are not well aligned with database pages (essentially unit of disk allocation). Instead, B-trees are pretty much universally used. And yes, you can have several B-tree indexes on top of the same table (you can have index on `userID` in this case). For better understanding, I warmly recommend reading [Anatomy of an SQL Index](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/anatomy) (and pretty much the entire http://use-the-index-luke.com/ site for that matter).

Comment: @user442920 And just to clarify Dour's answer: storing list is "wrong" because it violates the principle of [atomicity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form#Atomicity) and therefore 1NF. It will hurt your data integrity (which is generally more important than performance) and will ultimately hurt your performance as well, compared to a well-designed indexing scheme.