# From one big class to simple ones

Tags: c#, arrays, database, class, object

I know there are A LOT of the same questions, but I can't find the compination of words to find the right example, so..please help me.
I have a terrible class UlesanneDb with getters, setters, constructor and override ToString() to 53 fields in database.

```
    public string Variant { get; set; }
    public string r1 { get; set; }
    public string r2 { get; set; }
    public string r3 { get; set; }
    public string rone { get; set; }
    public string rtwo { get; set; }
    public string rthree { get; set; }
    public string functionname { get; set; }
    public string andmetype { get; set; }
    public string ulesannetype { get; set; }
    public string t { get; set; }

    public string joonkiirus1 { get; set; }
    public string joonkiirus2 { get; set; }
    public string joonkiirus3 { get; set; }
    public string joonkiirusA { get; set; }
    public string joonkiirusB { get; set; }
    public string joonkiirusC { get; set; }
    public string joonkiiruslatt { get; set; }
    public string joonkiiruskoormus { get; set; }

    public string nurkkiirus1 { get; set; }
    public string nurkkiirus2 { get; set; }
    public string nurkkiirus3 { get; set; }
    public string nurkkiirusA { get; set; }
    public string nurkkiirusB { get; set; }
    public string nurkkiirusC { get; set; }
```

and so on....
This is physics excersise - there is three wheels(1,2,3) and three points(a,b,c). For every wheel and point there are joonkiirus 1, nurkkiirus1 and so on.

So, I need to simplify this terrible thing. 
I think I need to create Classes like:

```
   class Wheels
   {    

        public double joonkiirus1 {get;set;}
        public double joonkiirus2 {get;set;}
        public double joonkiirus3 {get;set;}
        public double  nurkkiirus1 {get;set;}
        public double nurkiirendus1 {get;set;}
        // .....and so on for all the fields?
   }

   class Point
   {
      // or it should be like this
      int[] pointA = new int[6] {joonkiirus1, nurkkiirus1, nurkkiirendus1, tangkiirendus1, normaalkiirendus1, kogukiirendus}; //there are 6 physical things
      int[] pointB = new int[6]{same}; 
      int[] pointC = new int[6]{same};

   }
```

and then in UlesanneDb I need to use it like an OBJECT ARRAY. The thing is, I don't understand what I need to write in this class, so I can call it then in UlesanneDB as an object array and use it to initialize it with database fields...

```
  //so in 
    class UlesanneDb{
     int Variant {get;set;}
     // ?? something here is definitely wrong, but i can't figure out how and what place into array, what should be just variable
     Wheels wheel = new wheel {}
         }
```

You will actually save my sanity if you explain me this T_T Please/

Comment: are you talking about using a `List<Class>` also does the first set of get; set; belong to a class..? if so what class is that.. are you using nested classes or separate class files

Comment: If you are trying to create a `Wheels` class that contains all the information about all 3 wheel that's probably not the best way to go.  Instead create a `Wheel` class that contains the information for one wheel and then use a list or array of `Wheel` to represent all the wheels.  Same thing with points.  But it's hard to see if that's what you are doing since I have no idea what joonkiirus or nurkkiirus are.

Comment: You're right, that class design is no good, but your proposed alternative isn't great either. What you need is for instance a `Wheel` class, with the physical properties (one for each) `joonkiirus`, `nurkkiirus` etc. Then, if you have 3 wheels, you probably need an array of 3 `Wheel` objects (like `new Wheel[3]`) or 3 properties `Wheel1`, `Wheel2` `Wheel3`. Try to model your classes after the real objects: a wheel has one *joonkiirus* property, not 3 of them.

Comment: Someone's trying to migrate this question to Server Fault... seriously? :-\

Comment: So it should be like 
class Wheel {
public double joonkiirus;
public double nurkkiirus;
public double nurkkiirendus;
public dobule tangriikirendus;
public double normaalnekiirendus;
public double kogukiirendus;
}

class UlesanneDb{
Variant{get;set;}
.Wheel wheel = new Wheel [3];

}
how do i call it in UlesanneDB ?

Comment: or in UlesanneDB it should be like
 List<Wheel> wheel {get;set;} ... or for this dont need fet set.
but with what i should fill this list...how to pass there this joonkiirus1, 2 T_T

Comment: I recommend you to use [Codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) for a question like this. Get a working example then ask the question over there for optimization.

Comment: It's still not clear what are you trying to achieve. If I understand correctly, you have this ugly table in your database and you want to read data from database, normalize it and process it somehow?

Comment: look, unswers told me to create two classes like
`  class Point
    {
        public string joonkiirus;
        public string nurkkiirus;
        public string nurkkiirendus;
        public string tangriikirendus;
        public string normaalnekiirendus;
        public string kogukiirendus; 
    }`
and ' class Wheel
    {
        public string joonkiirus; 
        public string nurkkiirus; 
        public string nurkkiirendus; 
        public string tangriikirendus; 
        public string normaalnekiirendus;
        public string kogukiirendus; 
    }

soo, my UlesanneDB class now looks like

Comment: '  public string Variant { get; set; }
        public string rone { get; set; }
        public string rtwo { get; set; }
        public string rthree { get; set; }
        public string functionname { get; set; }
        public string andmetype { get; set; }
        public string ulesannetype { get; set; }
        public string t { get; set; }
        public List<Wheel> Wheel { get; set; }
        public List<Point> Point { get; set; }'

so...a need somehow now that in this list add fields - like in first terrible example - For wheel1 - all of the
for wheel2 all of them... and so on

Comment: and then how to write this in constructor...

Comment: Why do you have the same set of properties for `Point` and `Wheel`? How can `Point` contain speed related values?

Comment: The speed that smth was moving in this Point. So yes, they have the same proporties. And there are three wheels and three points. And i don't understand how to get three arrays of three lists and put there all of this things and then write it in conctructor how it was when class was terrible

Comment: We would need to see the full code for this class. English translations for some of the property names would also help attract a wider audience. I've actually dealt with a _really_ similar problem trying to map a table in the database with over 200 columns (no, really!) to a single object with over 200 properties. I'd love to post an answer to this question, but need more information.

Answer (score 1):

This is really more a comment than an answer, but it is too long for the comment field, and I suspect you will not get a satisfactory answer until you address a few problems in your question.

First, you need to [explain the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in enough detail with enough clarity that someone who doesn't have your software can understand what you have and what you're trying to do. You haven't done that. Learning how to express yourself is a critical skill and you will not become a successful software developer without learning how to do this.

Second, “53 fields in database” is a big danger sign that your data has not been [normalized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29930453/). You need to do this or you risk corrupting your data.

Another big danger sign is class properties named `something1`, `something2` and so on. This is a symptom of designing classes from the UI or output you will generate, and not on the data you are trying to model.

Yet another danger sign is many `string` data fields. Strings can store any kind of text data, including names, numbers, URLs, scripts, markup, or entire books. Can you really accept any one of those for every `string` field in your class? If not, you should use a more specialized data format.

Unfortunately I cannot suggest a design because I don't understand what you are trying to model; you have to explain that first.

Answer (score 0):

This is just an additin to great @Dour High Arch answer.

I think you need to edit this or even better create new question. Some suggestions:

- Explain from where this strange class with 53 properties comes. Is there a database table with same design? Why all properties are strings? Have you created this class yourself, or it's someones else and you can't change that?
- I think it will be easier for people to help you if you translate property names from Estonian to English (the same applies to `UlesanneDb`).
- Describe what are you trying to achieve. What data types do you need for calculations.

Good luck on SO!