# SQL Relationships in code

Tags: c#, sql, relationship

Okay. So I've got to do a database of a school, and I'm obligated to work with relationships to every table I create. So far I've got few tables and a few relationships, like this: I've got `Classrooms` table including `ID` and `ClassroomNumber` (like 101, 203 etc.). In another `Subjects` table I've got `SubjectName` and `ClassroomID` and a Relationship like this:

[image]

In code (C#) I `Select` values from `Classrooms` table, but I have to use `join`/`where`, so I add `where s.ClassroomID = c.ID` (s and c defined before). Okay, it works. But my question is different. Why am I obligated to use Relationships? What are they for? `Join` and `where` are working without relationships, so why?

Comment: Consult [Basic Database Design?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29930453/)

Comment: You aren't obligated. And if you have such a question, may be you've choose the wrong tool for the task you are facing. Sql DBs are perfect for many cases, nevertheless your milage may vary.

Comment: Man, I am. You know, I'm at college, they give me such an exercise with many, many requirements, and really, I have to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's for ensuring data integrity. Making sure that less shit data gets into the DB. Also to have a structure DB that also other people can easy understand.

Don't question it. You need them. You want them. In a DWH you don't, but in a Transactional DB you DO.

Answer (score 1):

Foreign keys are  indexes based on the relationship between the  tables/columns . This becomes very important the larger your table gets. If you attempted to join two tables with millions of records and had no indexes in place the query would take significantly longer to complete.