# How to Copy Needed columns from table to another table In C# Database

Tags: c#, sql, database, datatable, copy

Im developing an Attendence System.

I have a table named `Prefect` and other one is `Attendence`, I have prefects' details in prefects table
`Admission_ number,First_Name,Last_Name,Grade,class,gender`

I need to get Details `First Name` + `Last Name` , `grade` And `Class` from Prefects table and also need to save System time and System date with those data to `Attendence` table when i enter the `Admission_number`
..(in the program im using a barcode reader )

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You need to learn [Basic database design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29930453/).

Answer (score 1):

The way you are planning on creating your tables, you will end up with a lot to duplicated data. You should try to keep duplication (data redundancy) to a minimum.

What you should aim to do is.

Table 1: defines your students
Tables 2: Links to Table 1 for pupil details (and records the time and date)
In your example, you might get away with the above setup, normally, you end up needing bridging tables.

So

Student Table will have: 
UniqueID(PK),
FirstName,
LastName,
and so on...

Attendance: Table will have
UniqueID(Fk) (This will be the students unique ID),
Time,
Date,
and so on..

Your queries should pull the student details from student table using joins.

Hope this gives you some pointers towards what to look for..

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy..i don't know how to join tables that's why i m trying to do that thanks for your valuable information

Comment: Google sql joins,  they allow you to link tables and pull the information you need.  Look up relational databases and sql joins,  that would be a good start for you.  Good luck

Comment: thanks buddy realy appreciate your help